# Pointers to structure in Go Language

Tags: pointers, go

this is my code:

```
package main
import ("fmt")

type Message struct {

    Text []byte
    Tag string
}

func main() {

    var m Message

    pkt := []byte("Hey")
    editMessage(&m, &pkt)

    fmt.Println(string(m.Text))
    }

func editMessage(m *Message, pkt *[]byte) {

    m.Text = *pkt
}
```

And I get "Hey" as expected on the output.

If I change `m.Text = *pkt` with `(*m).Text = *pkt` It works as well!

Which is the correct/more efficient version? Or is it just a shortcut?

This thing doesn't now work all the time, if I use

```
c *net.Conn
```

as input in a function, I must use

```
something := (*c).RemoteAddr()
```

to get it working.

Thank you

Comment: note this doesn't come up in real code, because you should almost never use a pointer to an interface.

Comment: And you don't normally use pointers to slices (or maps, or strings) either. A slice is already a reference to to the underlying data so there is no need for extra indirection (unless you wanted to update the slice's length or capacity, but in many such cases it's better to return the resultant slice like `append` does).

Comment: I'm using it because I need to get the source IP address of a connection, inside a function, and to have better efficiency I passed the connection as reference instead of coping it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to [the Golang Language Specification - Method values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) section, you'll note this quote (emphasis mine):

> As with selectors, a reference to a **non-interface** method with a value receiver using a pointer will **automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv.**

Thus, your pointer is being automatically dereferenced for you.

`net.Conn` is an interface .. and as such, you must manually dereference the pointer in order for this to work.